# Error with instascan library: Uncaught abort()

Tags: instascan

i had three buttons for the scanning purposed start pause and resume well they worked fine when clicked once but threw the error (provided below) and it it kept on throwing this error (infinite times)
help me resolve this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qk5W.png)